# SearchActivity to search through an ArrayList<Obj>

Tags: java, android

I've coded this class that lets me search through an `ArrayList` displayed into a `RecyclerView`. This is the class:

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Accordo> chords;
    RecyclerView rv;
    SearchView sv;
    ArrayList<Accordo> filteredList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_layout);

        /** gestisce la pubblicita */
        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

        AdView searchBanner = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.search_ad);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        searchBanner.loadAd(adRequest);

        /**-------------------------------*/

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        chords = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("chords");
        filteredList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("chords");

        sv = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.testo_ricerca);
        sv.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.lista_ricerca);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(SearchActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final SearchAdapter adapter = new SearchAdapter(this, chords);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        //SEARCH
        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //FILTER AS YOU TYPE
                List<Accordo> filteredModelList = filter(chords, newText);
                adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
                return true;
            }
        });

        /** gestisce cosa succede quando un elemento della lista viene cliccato */
        ItemClickSupport.addTo(rv).setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, ChordActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelable("selected", filteredList.get(position));
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    private List<Accordo> filter(List<Accordo> models, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();

        filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Accordo model : models) {
            final String text = model.getName().toLowerCase();
            if (text.contains(query)) {
                filteredList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredList;
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code above, it is based on a filter that every time the user types something in the search box, creates a filteredList and puts it into the `RecyclerView`. Of course when the user did not type anything the filteredList should have contained the whole `ArrayList chords`

So I was getting an error (NPE) when I clicked on an Item while nothing had been typed into the search box, because the filteredList was null. I managed to solve it by having both:

```
chords = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("chords");
```

**`filteredList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("chords");`**

I think this is a huge waste of memory and resources since we are talking about an ArrayList with ca 300 elements, each of which has 5 images, strings and sounds.

**Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same result?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Once is enough of `bundle.getParcelableArrayList("chords")`

I'm not sure if `bundle.getParcelableArrayList` creates a new list every time it's called. If it doesn't, then repeated calls won't double the memory used so it won't really be a problem.
But in any case, you don't need to call it twice like this:

> ```
> chords = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("chords");
> filteredList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("chords");
> ```

You can make `filteredList` reference `chords`:

```
filteredList = chords = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("chords");
```

#### Use interfaces in declarations

These fields would be better declared as `List` instead of `ArrayList`:

> ```
> ArrayList<Accordo> chords;
> ArrayList<Accordo> filteredList;
> ```

Just like you used `List` instead of `ArrayList` in the `filter` method.

Also, probably all fields of the activity should be `private`.

#### Reduce memory churn

Every time the query text changes,
you recreate a new list,
and re-link the adapter to the new list.
It might be more efficient to reuse the same list,
by clearing and re-adding elements instead of creating a new list.
However,
there is just one tricky point,
of the initial state when there is no filter yet.
The adapter could initially be linked to `chords`,
and then the first time a query text is entered,
re-link it to `filteredList`, for example:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if (filteredList == null) {
        // first time used
        filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter.setFilter(filteredList);
    }
    filter(newText);
    return true;
}

private void filter(String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();

    filteredList.clear();
    for (Accordo model : chords) {
        final String text = model.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(query)) {
            filteredList.add(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice some other related changes:

- I dropped the list parameter of `filter`: the filtering is always based on `chords`, which is a field, so the method has direct access to it, no need to pass as parameter
- Made `filter` return `void`, as now it modifies `filteredList` in-place

Comment: Great answer!! Thank you a lot! Just one thing, if I change filteredList and chords from `ArrayList` to `List` I cannot use `bundle.getParcelableArrayList`, is there something I could use instead?